# Colnames unexpectedly updating variable in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a list of column names that have been added after the initial csv load. If I am not updating the variable after column names are added, then how are they being added to the variable?

I would expect that only Name and Age would get printed from my_cols but it is printing IsJon as well

```
library(data.table)

Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.table(Name, Age)

my_cols <- colnames(df)

print(my_cols)

df[,isJon:=ifelse(Name=="John", 1, 0)]

print(my_cols)
```

Comment: Yes, this is a difficult one to explain, and I don't think I can do it justice. `data.table` is an outlier (from most of R) in that most of what it does, it does with *reference* semantics, meaning updates and such is done *in-place*. In this case, *somehow* (yes, this is where I don't have the details), the `my_cols` is not a copy of the names, it is a *pointer* to where the names are stored. This means that when the column is added, the pointer to where names are stored is pointing to the same place that now has *three* names, not just two.

Comment: *However*, if you started with `my_cols <- copy(colnames(df))`, then your assumptions work just fine, and the second look at `my_cols` is still length-2.

Comment: I figured that was happening but I feel that I have done this many times and this is the first time I'm seeing these results. Thanks much for the copy technique

Comment: @r2evans, post as answer?

Comment: I also think it is related to R's lazy operations. That is, instead of `my_cols <- copy(colnames(df))` you did `my_cols <- c(colnames(df), "A")`, the variable `my_cols` *does not include `"isJon"`, because the `c`oncatenation forced R to evaluate and copy-in-place (ergo it's copy-on-write semantics).

Comment: @BenBolker, yeah, I was just leaning there, I was hoping a more-`data.table`-guru would come along with references to documentation or better explanations than what I feel is hand-waving ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two things going on here:

- R is inherently *lazy* with objects, and when you create `my_cols <- colnames(df)`, it isn't changing anything so it does not create a duplicate vector of names. The moment you do something to the vector of names that "could" be changing it, R copies the vector from the frame's attributes and creates a new one, thereby not changing when the original frame is updated.
- `data.table` tends to do things *in-place* with its referential semantics, so when it adds a column, the internal storage of column names is appended in-place, contrary to R's normal way of doing things. Normally, `data.frame` changes creates a new vector of names when you add one.

  C.f., `base::data.frame`, adding a column creates a new vector of column names, therefore our `my_cols` does not magically stay updated:

  ```r
  Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
  Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
  df <- data.frame(Name, Age)
  my_cols <- colnames(df)
  print(my_cols)
  # [1] "Name" "Age" 
  df <- transform(df, isJon=ifelse(Name=="John", 1, 0))
  print(my_cols)
  # [1] "Name" "Age"
  ```

There a couple of ways you can get these two things to work in the direction you were heading:

1. `copy` the vector, which forces it to be a new copy (yes, good name) of the vector.

   ```r
   Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
   Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
   df <- data.table(Name, Age)
   my_cols <- copy(colnames(df))
   print(my_cols)
   # [1] "Name" "Age" 
   df[,isJon:=ifelse(Name=="John", 1, 0)]
   print(my_cols)
   # [1] "Name" "Age"
   ```
2. Do "something" to the vector, making R think it should copy-on-write:

   ```r
   Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
   Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
   df <- data.table(Name, Age)
   my_cols <- colnames(df)[]
   print(my_cols)
   # [1] "Name" "Age" 
   df[,isJon:=ifelse(Name=="John", 1, 0)]
   print(my_cols)
   # [1] "Name" "Age"
   ```

Comment: I believe I had always "did something" to the vector like a grep of colnames. Thanks much!